# Playing video from server url in android default player

Tags: android, http, video, playing

I need to play video in android default video player(which are installed in android device). The video is coming from server.

i am using the following logic :

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri data = Uri.parse("http://166.78.178.47:8080/android/Videos/469_1402667888305.mp4");
                intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
                startActivity(intent);
```

and i used following in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

But it is not playing. It gives black screen.

Comment: You can try `VideoView` and set the path using `videoView.setVideoURI(data);`

Comment: You should go to [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10461150/1289716)

Comment: how did you get your server to play the video from that URL? i am having troubles trying to figure that out for mine :/