# Change source code for video location

Tags: android-studio

I recently purchase a source code for a quiz app, doing so with no experience. The app allows video to be played, but requires you to "tap to play", I would like for the video to play on the same screen as the question. How do I change this and can I change this in this line of code? New to this, so if you need any additional info, let me know.

```
 else if(question.questionType == 3) {
        mSmallLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTapText.setText(R.string.tap_to_play);
        File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/delete" + mCurrentQuestion);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            mSmallImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
        } else {
            mSmallImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.videooverlay);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it won't let me put a screen shot of the actual app because I need a higher rating,

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to open it using an Android Edition Platform, The code is like:
JAVA:

> ```
>     public void onClickBtn(View v)
>     {
>         Toast.makeText(this, "Lets try").show();
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> Button[Onclick function]:
>
> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/btn"
>     android:onClick="onClickBtn" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

And video example:

**[Playing a video in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461119/playing-a-video-in-android)**

// Additional info: The Android Manifest is a android XML to execute the JAVA code, To work on you need check the Android dev's page and check every function, An function to be ready, Need to be set righty. Thank you!